# Django: Two fields are unique but still fail UNIQUE constraint

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-models

I am writing some test to check the model I have for a basic blog app. The model requires that blog titles be unique. The following is the body of the test I have written to save two blog posts:

```
    first_post.title = "First Post!"
    first_post.body = "This is the body of the first post"
    first_post.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
    first_post.tags = all_tags[0]
    first_post.slug = "first_post"
    first_post.save()


    second_post = Post()
    second_post.title = "Second Post!"
    self.assertNotEqual(first_post.title,second_post.title)
    second_post.body = "This is the body of the Second post"
    second_post.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
    second_post.tags = all_tags[1]
    second_post.slug = "second"
    second_post.save()
```

Note the `self.assertNotEqual(first_post.title, second_post.title)`. I added this because when I run the test I keep getting `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: blog_post.title_text`. When I did through the rest of the vomitext that is spit out with this it points to `second_post.save()`. However, the `assertNotEqual` always passes, if I change it to `assertEqual` it fails.

No matter what I put into the title value I get the same error. Why are these two Post objects considered to have the same title?

For reference, here is the blog model:

```
class  Post(models.Model):
    title_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    post_tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
    post_body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field in your model is named `title_text`, but in your test you use `title`. So the db value of `title_text` will be "" in both cases.

Change to this:

```
first_post.title_text = "First Post!"
first_post.body = "This is the body of the first post"
first_post.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
first_post.tags = all_tags[0]
first_post.slug = "first_post"
first_post.save()


second_post = Post()
second_post.title_text = "Second Post!"
self.assertNotEqual(first_post.title_text,second_post.title_text)
second_post.body = "This is the body of the Second post"
second_post.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
second_post.tags = all_tags[1]
second_post.slug = "second"
second_post.save()
```

Comment: Man, need more coffee. Good spot! Thanks. Ill accept once the time limit lets me.